# Joining sql query with three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, transactions

I have to join three tables.

1 table is transaction , next table is shops, 3rd is weather.

I want to fetch data from all of these three ,but in case of weather table > id,tamp_c,datetime column name .

The query is:-

```
 select HOUR(transaction.time) as Hour ,
        TRUNCATE(sum(transaction.total),2) as Total_Sales,
        shops.gstIncludedSales as GST_Inc_Sales,
        shops.gstFreeSales as GST_Free,weather.temp_c 
        from transaction,shops,weather 
        where transaction.shopid=shops.id and transaction.shopid=7
        and transaction.transaction_date ='2015-05-25' 
        group by hour 
        ORDER BY hour DESC
```

The problem is that I want to apply a `where` clause with `weather.datetime` table separation for particular date like `time(datetime)='2015-05-25'`, but it's not working.

Comment: have you tried `date(weather.datetime)='2015-05-25'`?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a join condition for weather to either of the other tables. What results do you get back, what do you expect?

Comment: thanks for reply Paul  i want to fetch this table also SELECT * FROM `weather` WHERE date(datetime)='2015-05-25' and shop_id=7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

WHERE transaction.transaction_date >= '2015-05-25' AND transaction.transaction_date  < '2015-05-26'

That will return rows with timestamp during the whole day (midnight until midnight - time is implied).

If you have SQLServer 2014 you canm use DATE(transaction.transaction_date).

Comment: alternatively _WHERE transaction.transaction_date BETWEEN  '2015-05-25' AND '2015-05-26'_ or DATE function (assuming MySQL)

Comment: You would also get records from 2015-05-26 00:00:00 with that between statement. Date function is in my answer already :)

Comment: You are right - just noticed the data I was testing on did not have any data for the following day - so appeared to work. The Date function - I was commenting this is available in MySQL as well as SQLServer 2014

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want

```
SELECT HOUR(transaction.time) as Hour ,
   TRUNCATE(sum(transaction.total),2) as Total_Sales,
   shops.gstIncludedSales as GST_Inc_Sales,
   shops.gstFreeSales as GST_Free,weather.temp_c 
FROM transaction
JOIN shops ON transaction.shopid=shops.id
JOIN weather ON DATE(transaction.transaction_date) = DATE(weather.datetime)
WHERE DATE(transaction.transaction_date)='2015-05-25' AND transaction.shopid=7
GROUP by hour 
ORDER BY hour DESC
```

(Assuming you are using MySQL)

Comment: Thanks for reply but my problem is that date column is also in transaction table as well as weather table also datetime  column so i want the record from weather table with where clause  date(weather.datetime)='2015-05-25'so both individual date is used on different table. thanks in Advance

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - can you show the schema of the three tables & give some example expected results.

Comment: weather=>
 id
 shop_id 
 temp_c
 datetime
shops=>
 id
  gstIncludedSales
 GST_Inc_Sales,
  gstFreeSales
transacion=>
 id
 transaction 
 total
 time

Comment: select HOUR(transaction.time) as Hour ,TRUNCATE(sum(transaction.total),2) as Total_Sales,shops.gstIncludedSales as GST_Inc_Sales,shops.gstFreeSales as GST_Free from transaction,shops where transaction.shopid=shops.id and transaction.shopid=7 and transaction.transaction_date ='2015-05-25' group by hour ORDER BY hour DESC  i want to join this query result with SELECT * FROM weather WHERE date(datetime)='2015-05-25' and shop_id=7 thanks in Advance .

Comment: In your comment showing table schema transaction.shopid is missing is that an oversight.

Comment: thanks for reply @PaulF no its there in shopid also in transaction table my expected result is that  | Hours from transaction |   total_sales from transaction | gstIncludedSales from shops | gstFreeSales from shops| temp_c from weather table|  all data fetch in a single query.

Comment: `SELECT HOUR(transaction.time) as Hour ,
   TRUNCATE(sum(transaction.total),2) as Total_Sales,
   shops.gstIncludedSales as GST_Inc_Sales,
   shops.gstFreeSales as GST_Free,weather.temp_c 
FROM transaction
JOIN shops ON transaction.shopid=shops.id
JOIN weather ON transaction.shopid=weather.shop_id
WHERE DATE(transaction.transaction_date)='2015-05-25' AND transaction.shopid=7 AND DATE(transaction.transaction_date) = DATE(weather.datetime)
GROUP by hour 
ORDER BY hour DESC`